# How is Handlebars handling of ".." (up level) correct?

Tags: handlebars.js

Using Handlebars Cookbook for example material...

**Data:**

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "moo": "No"
    }
  },
  "moo": "Yes!"
}
```

**Template:**

```
{{#foo.bar}}
{{../moo}}
{{/foo.bar}}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Yes!
```

This just seems wrong to me, and I'm hoping someone can help me with the logic.

If Handlebars navigates context down the first lookup "foo.bar", the context inside the block should be bar, or `{"moo":"No"}`.  In fact it seems to be.  If I put `{{moo}}` in the block body I'd see "No" for output.

So it would seem logical that, ".." goes up 1 level to context foo, `{"bar":{"moo","No"}}`.  There is no "moo" in the "foo" object.  The logical/expected way to get "Yes!" would be to use `{{../../moo}}`, but that's not how it works.

What is the logic here?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see.  I'm assuming (wrongly) that Handlebars resolves each path component into a context: `Context[foo] -> Context[bar]`.  That's not how it seems to work.  Rather it creates `Context[foo.bar]`.   So ".." from that is indeed root, so "../moo" is "Yes!".

It's **not** a path stack in the programming sense, but seemly rather a stack/history of block contexts.